# How to call and run function from string c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm a student, I'm studying how to analytics and using parameters of the function from file.txt

File.txt content example:

```
int Add(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
```

Return_Value = "int"

Parameter = "int a, int b"

But I do not know how to use the parameters to call function with String.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/826435/194717

Comment: What do you mean by "call function with String"?

Comment: Yes. I want to "call function with String" with c#

Comment: You will either have to compile the code in that text file, or add/implement a programming language that matches the syntax. Neither is easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5391560/4121996), I should be able to call a function by name, put return values in parameter/arguments list or within the parentheses, which passes them back, e.g.:

```
public void Add1 (a, b)
{
    // Call Add2, passing arguments Add1 received
    Add2(a, b);
}

public void Add2 (a, b)
{
    // code goes here for what to do with passed arguments
}

// This calls the function and passes parameters back
```